# winforms identifiers are not visible

Tags: c++, winforms

I have a button click event handler that draws a graph.

```
    System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
     {
           . . .
    }
```

then I decided to put the drawing of the graph into a separate function, since I would have to call it for the timer.and I got the following.many indentifiers turned out to be undefined:
[image]

I tried to follow the VS prompts but it didn't help either
[image]

at the same time, I have defined at the beginning of the cpp file:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
```

tell me, what should I do to make them visible again?What should I write?

Comment: @AlexF Yes, I understand. But I don't need to associate this method with pressing a button. Therefore, I need to define it separately somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a reference to the `System::Drawing` assembly. Add

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

at the top of your program. `System::Windows::Forms` contains classes related to, well, forms and controls. `System::Drawing` contains class related to, well, drawing.

Comment: oh, a lot of bugs are gone, thanks. but it still writes to me that picturebox1 is not defined and  the "this" operator can only be used inside a non-static member function

Comment: please tell me how to solve the remaining two errors?

Comment: The compiler is telling you that your `draw1` function needs to be a member function of your `MyForm` class. The `this` variable is only avaiable inside of non-static member functions, and `draw1` is a global function.

Comment: I tried to do so: void MyForm::draw1() .but that's not enough, is it?Could you complete your answer if you know, please?I'm just trying in every possible way, and so far nothing comes out.

Comment: Well, in C++ you have to declare your method in the class definition. So wherever your `class MyForm` is located, you need to add a declaration like `void draw1();` This is elementary C++: how familiar are you with the language?

Comment: I've already figured it out, thanks. I wondered why it didn't work out the previous times, apparently I made typos.